# Trying to add a card to trello fails

Tags: node.js, trello

I am trying to add a card to trello using a Node.js script.  Other calls (all gets so far) to the trello system seem to be working, but this one just doesn't return any response at all.  I tried plugging it into an API tester (postman) and I get back this error message:

This seems to be like an error connecting to http://URL: https://api.trello.com/1/cards?name=TestCard&pos=top&due=null&idlist=[listid]&key=[key]&token=[token]. The response status was 0.
Check out the W3C XMLHttpRequest Level 2 spec for more details about when this happens.

Edit: Postman now returns the correct response (in 0.5s), with the change to capitalization called out in the comments below.  However, my code times out after 3s.  So something is wrong in the code after all.

This is the first Post call I've tried to implement, so that could be the problem here.  My code looks like this:

```
var options = {
  hostname: api.trello.com, 
  port: 443,
  path: '/1/cards?name=TestCard&pos=top&due=null&idList=[listid]&key=[key]&token=[token]',
  method: 'POST',
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json'}
};
https.request(options, function(res) {
    var ResponseString = '';
    console.log("statusCode: ", res.statusCode);
    console.log("headers: ", res.headers);
    //and more code here
});
```

The res.on('data') and res.on('end') functions both have console.logs and don't get called.  The console.logs from this function don't get called either.

I have also tried the lists/[ListID]/cards?due=null&name=[CardTitle] url, without any response from that one either.

Is there something I need to know about posting from Node.js that I'm missing here?

Comment: I tested this as a "PUT" as well, just for laffs, and got no response from that either (I was expecting at least an error message, perhaps).

Comment: I am aware of this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31644818/trying-to-add-a-card-to-trello-fails but as it's over a year old, and the correct "answer" (it's a comment, but it solved the problem) is "use application/json as a content-type" I don't think this is a duplicate.

Comment: You want `idList` (note capitalization), but I would expect that to cause a pretty clear error, so there might be something else wrong.

Comment: Also, your link in that comment is to this question, so I think you pasted the wrong thing.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25685445/creating-a-new-card-using-the-trello-api - thanks for catching that :)

Comment: Either capitalization was the problem, or Trello have fixed the API, because the POST test in Postman works now.  However, my code still times out.  Postman returns in about 0.5 seconds, but my code times out after 3 seconds.  I'll edit the question to reflect this.

Comment: Data in a POST request must be in the body.  Putting it in the query string will not work.

Comment: Testing this call through Postman works - the test card is created successfully.  Also, the https module documentation for Node says: "path: Request path. Defaults to '/'. Should include query string if any. E.G. '/index.html?page=12'" - so this doesn't seem like the problem.  In fact, I straight up can't see a place to add a "body" to https.request.

Comment: Check the documentation for `https.request`.  It returns an object, and you must call `.end()` on that object or the request never gets sent.

Comment: Yes, I have a res.on(end) event handler - I wasn't expecting the problem to be in code when the API tester wasn't working, so this was just a snippet of code - I'll edit in the rest when I am home from work later.

Comment: sorry, I mis-read that - you're right, I am not calling .end on that - I'll test that later, but it looks like the answer.  If you make it into one, I will accept it if this works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`https.request` returns a `ClientRequest` object.  You can use this object to add a body to the request (with `req.write()`).  But, more importantly, the request isn't completed until you call `req.end()`; it expects that you haven't finished setting up the body yet if you fail to call that.

Comment: That worked.  Thanks for the help!  The parameters do work in the querystring, but the req.end() call was missing.